# OpenCV: Track co-ordinates of expanding rectangle

Tags: python, opencv

I have a calibration process in which I want to get the maximum height and width of the screen. So I made a growing rectangle of which I want co-ordinates by image processing. This rectangle will always be viewed at an angle.

I have used a coloured rectangle to detect it in HSV range but it doesn't seems to be working. First I detect the green coloured rectangle then threshold it then detect canny edges then find contours and filter the largest contour. Final contour with approximation is shown in 'img' tab in screenshot.

The problem here is the further edge of the green rectangle appears black and doesn't get detected in HSV range. So the maximum width and height is not obtained. Even if I have the top-left and bottom-right corner of the rectangle in edge detection.

Is there a way other to track scaling rectangle other than detecting HSV range of coloured rectangle. Since the rectangle is moving there should be.

CODE:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture('rectCalibration2.mp4')
img = np.zeros((360,640,3))
prevImg = np.zeros((360,640,3))
finalContour = []
end_time = time.time() + 15
largestArea = 5000
while(video.isOpened()):
 _, frame = video.read()
 if frame is None:
  print('ended')
  break
 frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 360))
 hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
 greenLower = (55, 100, 6)
 greenUpper = (70, 255, 255)
 mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, greenLower, greenUpper)
 th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(mask,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
 th = cv2.erode(th, None, iterations=3)
 th = cv2.dilate(th, None, iterations=3)
 edges = cv2.Canny(th,200,400)
 m, contours, hierarchy = 
 cv2.findContours(edges,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

 largeContours = []

 for contour in contours:
   area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
   if area > largestArea:
     largestArea = area
     largeContours.append(contour)
     finalContour = contour
     img = np.zeros((360,640,3))
     cv2.drawContours(img, largeContours, -1, (255, 255, 255))
     prevImg = img

 if (prevImg is not img):
   end_time = time.time() + 15

 if time.time() > end_time:
   epsilon = 0.1 * cv2.arcLength(finalContour, True)
   approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(finalContour, epsilon, True)
   print(approx)
   prevImg = np.zeros((360,640,3))
   cv2.drawContours(prevImg,[approx],0,(255,255,255),2)
   cv2.imshow('final', prevImg)
   video.release()
   break

cv2.imshow('frame',frame) 
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('edges', edges)
if cv2.waitKey(33) == ord('q'):
  video.release()
  break
```

[Small Rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwDdy.png)

[Frame, Edges, Contours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EK6L.png)

The 'img' tab shows the finalContour which is not of the maximum width and height

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated scheme - why not just make the whole screen a single colour (or a sequence of whole screen a single colour)?